# C++ implicit class to char* conversion

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, char, implicit, typecasting-operator

I'm doing an exercise right now, so I will say right away that I don't want to use std::string to solve my problem.

I have a simple class that has a few fields and among them is char* text field that can be assigned and re-written or re-allocated.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  char* name;
...
public:
  operator char*() const { return name;}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make an implicit conversion to char* so that I can do this in my program:

```
Myclass s = "Hello"    //allocates 6 bytes and pust a 0-terminated "Hello/0" line into "name"

char* c = s

s = "Hello World"      //re-allocates memory, frees previous memory

cout << "Str: " << s << " Char: " << c;
```

Obviously, just as I noticed even before testing, when the re-allocation of "name" happens and the memory is freed - "c" now points to garbage.
So this code is no-go and I fully understand why.

I could allocate new memory and return a pointer to it, I guess:

```
operator char*() const
{
  int length = strlen(name)+1;
  char* ptr = new char[length]
  std::copy(name, name+length, ptr);
  return ptr;
}
```

but in this case, if I later re-assign "c" to something else - then the memory will never be freed, right? If I do this:

```
c = "Bye";
```

then basically the memory that I copied "name" to will still remain allocated and leaK?

The question is: how to make this right? Should I even worry about this, or do I simply assume that the user who re-assigns "c" should take care of clearing the memory first?

I will repeat that my goal is to do this through memory manipulation and pointers rather than safely use std::string.
Thank you!

Comment: The caller will have to remember not to use `c` after the string was reallocated, there's no way of avoiding that (unless you stop using raw pointers)

Comment: Consider [std::string::c_str()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) ...  `The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by ... Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend()`

Comment: You essentially want to attach ownership semantics information to the returned pointer. The only way to do that in C++ is by wrapping it in another type. Otherwise, it's probably best to hold on to the ownership yourself and threaten clients with nasal demons if they don't behave.

Comment: As an aside, implicit conversions to pointer types have another nasty side, they make code like `delete s;` compile and run. You definitely don't want that to happen.

Comment: Side note: You might prefer a pointer to const (`char const*`). Be aware that string literals themselfves are pointers to const as well.

Comment: I assume you want to avoid string *copying* - would be a cast to (const?) reference to std::string a valid alternative for you?

Comment: No, I don't want to use std::string AT ALL. This is an exercise in direct memory manipulation, not an attempt to do things the right way. The right way is to use many pre-built tools and classes. I want to understand the direct way better, how is it working under the hood.